# Handling display rotation in Android

Tags: android

I am new the Android. In my application development, I want to handle the display (screen) rotation. Is there any listener is available to handle this event? Or is there any alternate way to handle this situation?

Thanks & Regards,

Bala

Comment: If all you're trying to do is handle the fact that it destroys your Activity on rotation, see the discussion for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android). Specifically, use of Fragments seems to be the recommended way to handle this as you can specify that the Fragment not be destroyed on rotation. If you have something more general you want to do on rotation, @SteD's answer is correct. Note however that this is recommended against in the [Android API doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say you want to handle the orientation change yourself, use `configChanges="orientation"` in your activity in the manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now when one of these configurations change, MyActivity is not restarted. Instead, the Activity receives a call to `onConfigurationChanged().`

More details here: [Handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 3):

When developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), include "screenSize" in addition to "orientation".

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Create class "ScreenOrientationListener":

```
class ScreenOrientationListener @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context) :
MutableLiveData<Boolean>() {

private var screenWasRotated: Boolean = false

private var screenRotationListener: OrientationEventListener? = null

private fun registerScreenRotationListener() {
    //reset
    screenWasRotated = false

    screenRotationListener = object :
        OrientationEventListener(appContext, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
        override fun onOrientationChanged(p0: Int) {
            if (!screenWasRotated) {
                if ((appContext.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && p0 in 90..290) ||
                    (appContext.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && p0 in 0..70)
                ) {
                    screenWasRotated = true
                    screenRotationListener?.disable()
                    postValue(screenWasRotated)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (screenRotationListener?.canDetectOrientation() == true) {
        screenRotationListener?.enable()
    } else {
        screenRotationListener?.disable()
    }
}

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    registerScreenRotationListener()
}

override fun onInactive() {
    screenRotationListener?.disable()
    screenRotationListener = null

    super.onInactive()
}

override fun getValue() = screenWasRotated 
}
```

I usage Dagger to initialize it in view model:

```
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @HiltViewModel
    open class MyViewModel

    @Inject
    constructor(
       val screenOrientationListener: ScreenOrientationListener
    ) : ViewModel() {}
```

But you can just initialize it by:

```
val screenOrientationListener = ScreenOrientationListener(this)
```

How to use it:

```
screenOrientationListener.observe(this, {
        if(it){
           //Do something if screen was rotated
        }
})
```